# How to change the file read, create , write operations in specific folder on windows? what is the analog of OSXFUSE in windows?

Tags: file-read, virtual-drive, osxfuse

I want to change the file read, write, copy, delete operations in specific folders on my windows? On macos there is a OSXFUSE allowing to mount the desired folders and change the behavior of these operations. How to do the same on windows?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion here. OSXFUSE lets you create a virtual filesystem, where the data resides anywhere (possibly in certain directory on the disk). On Windows the same can be done with our [CBFS Connect](https://www.callbacktechnologies.com/cbfsconnect) product. If you want to expose directory /x as a virtual directory /y and control the operations performed on /y/* files , CBFS Connect includes FolderDrive sample which does exactly this.

On the other hand if you want to intercept access to certain files on the disk (say to /x/* files in the above example), in Windows this is done by the filesystem filter driver. This is not what OSXFUSE can do on MacOS. You can create your own filter driver or use our CBFS Filter.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the clear answer. Does MacOS have analogs to the file-system filter drivers?

Comment: @user3201666 MacOS has some notification technology but not as advanced filtering as Windows does.